# Validation React

Tags: reactjs, validation

How I would I use this validation without reduxForm.
I know how it is done with reduxForm but the guy above me wants this built without ReduxForm. So Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
onAddHistory = (field) => (response, index, value) => {
  const { history } = this.state;
  console.log(this.state);
  if (field === 'employerName' || field === 'description') {
    history[field] = response.target.value;
  } else if (field === 'roles') {
    history[field] = value;
  } else {
    history[field] = response.value;
  }
  this.setState({
    history: this.state.history,
  }
 }

isValid = () => {
  const errors = {};
  const regex = ***** to long to post

  if (!history.employerName || Validator.isNull(history.employerName)) 
   {errors.employerName = translations.translate('common', 
   'thisFieldIsRequired');}

this.setState({
  errors,
});

  return isEmpty(errors);
}
```

Then the errors would pass into the fields as 
Any ideas? Thank you ahead of time...

Comment: There are any number of ways to do validation outside of redux-form. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: Where do I pass isValid, does it pass into onAddHistory?

Comment: Where you call `isValid` depends on how things are structured; I'd guess no, since that looks to be handling the response from an Ajax call, e.g., after the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following approach:

(1) Given an input component, attach an `onChange` event handler

(2) In the definition for the `onChange` event handler, pass your field information (such as name, value, etc) to some validation method.

(3) Determine the validation error from the output of your validation method and store it somewhere (e.g. component state).

You can use `event.target.value`, `event.target.name`, etc to get information about the target field.

Your if statements in the `onAddHistory` method seem a bit convoluted. Please keep in mind when you want to change the state of a component, you always need to create a new object and substitute it on top of the existing state using `setState()`. In other words, you should never mutate `this.state` directly.

**SomeForm component example (only a snippet, not the whole thing):**

```
onFruitChange = (event) => {
  let error = null;

  // Validations (refactor with a helper validation function)
  if (event.target.value === '') {
    // Given value was blank, but the field is required
    error = `${event.target.name} is a required field`;
  }
  else if (event.target.value.length < 3) {
    // Given value must be at least 3 characters
    error = `${event.target.name} must contain at least 3 characters';
  }
  // else if ... other validation conditions

  this.setState({ fruit: event.target.value, fruitError: error });
}

render() {
  return (
    // ...
    <input type="text" name="fruit" value={this.state.fruit} onChange={this.onFruitChange} />
  )
}
```

In the example above, `this.state.fruitError` will indicate whether you have a validation error (its value is the error description).

Comment: The issue w/ `onChange` validation is that it may provide feedback before it makes sense to, and if the form isn't set up for input-specific error messaging (e.g., errors are at the top) doing it `onChange` is premature. Not disagreeing with the general idea, just that it doesn't work for all scenarios. (And you'd likely need to debounce any Ajax validation, although that doesn't appear to be relevant here.)

Comment: Oh, I just thought he wanted validation like that. The onChange would only fire after the form field had been touched (changed). To validate the whole form, you would have to look at each field again. If one wants validation only after clicking Submit, then I think it would be a lot easier. Just go through all the stored values and see if it is valid.